# Motion of omnidirectional robot in 2D with constant heading, which nav stack planner to use?

Tags: navigation, ubuntu, ros-noetic, path-planning, teb-local-planner

I am trying to make simple navigation example in ROS noetic of an omnidirectional robot (e.g. clearparth's ridgeback).

My goal is to always maintain the orientation of the robot wrt the /map frame during the robot's motion so practically I want twist commands with only linear velocities $\dot X, \dot Y$ and $\dot \theta = 0$ .

*With which local and global planners of the navigation stack could I achieve such a behavior?*

NOTE: I have been using the teb local planner along with the NavfnRos global planner. I have achieve a behavior close to the what I have described above but it is not optimal. What I did is to set the config params of the TEB planner (I put here the ones I deem important):

```
TebLocalPlannerROS:
  global_plan_overwrite_orientation: True
  
  max_vel_x: 0.5
  max_vel_y: 2.0 # To enable omnidirectional motion planning
  max_vel_x_backwards: 0.5
  max_vel_theta: 0.02 # Small theta vel to maintain heading
  acc_lim_x: 0.5
  acc_lim_y: 0.5 # To enable omnidirectional motion planning
  acc_lim_theta: 0.5

  penalty_epsilon: 0.01
  weight_max_vel_x: 2
  weight_max_vel_theta: 1
  weight_acc_lim_x: 1
  weight_acc_lim_theta: 1
  weight_kinematics_nh: 1 # To enable omnidirectional motion planning
```

**Note: It seems imposible to set both max_vel_theta and acc_lim_theta to zero.**

*Is there probably a way to configure the teb planner to create local paths while respecting a constant heading of the robot?*

Thank you